# How to divide hour in Oracle Database

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the following query, but I have a little problem

```
...
    trunc(to_char(to_date(elapsed_time,'hh24:mi:ss'),'sssss')/EXECUTIONS,2)

        ERROR at line 2:
        ORA-01850: hour must be between 0 and 23
...
```

That is happening because the elapsed_time is the sum of all queries and the value is above 24h.

How can I divide the value?

If you need, here is two queries, one about all elapsed_time and the other is the query with the issue, the query with the issue is a query that takes the average by execution

```
--TOP QUERIES COM MAIOR ELAPSED_TIME
set pagesize 0 embedded on;
set linesize 3000;
col FIRST_LOAD_TIME for a20;
col LAST_LOAD_TIME for a20;
col EXECUTIONS for a10;
COL sql_id for a20;
col FETCHES for a10;
col PARSE_CALLS for a15;
col elapsed_time for a20;
SELECT * FROM
(SELECT
    sql_id,
    TO_CHAR(TRUNC((elapsed_time/1000000)/3600),'FM9900') || ':' ||
    TO_CHAR(TRUNC(MOD((elapsed_time/1000000),3600)/60),'FM00') || ':' ||
    TO_CHAR(MOD((elapsed_time/1000000),60),'FM00') AS elapsed_time, --ESSE CAMPO É A SOMA DE TODO O TEMPO DE ESPERA, NAO DE APENAS UMA EXECUCAO
    child_number,
    disk_reads,
    to_char(executions) as executions,
    to_char(FETCHES) as FETCHES,
    to_char(PARSE_CALLS) as PARSE_CALLS,
    first_load_time,
    last_load_time
FROM    gv$sql
ORDER BY elapsed_time DESC)
WHERE ROWNUM < 10 ---top 10
/
```

The query that I want to build by average time:

```
--MEDIA ELAPSED_TIME POR EXECUCAO
set pagesize 0 embedded on;
set linesize 3000;
col FIRST_LOAD_TIME for a20;
col LAST_LOAD_TIME for a20;
col EXECUTIONS for a10;
COL sql_id for a20;
col FETCHES for a10;
col PARSE_CALLS for a15;
col TOTAL_ELAPSED_TIME_SECS for a40;
SELECT sql_id,elapsed_time,to_char(to_date(elapsed_time,'hh24:mi:ss'),'sssss') "TOTAL_ELAPSED_TIME_SECS",
EXECUTIONS,trunc(to_char(to_date(elapsed_time,'hh24:mi:ss'),'sssss')/EXECUTIONS,2) "AVG_TIME_BY_EXECUTION_SEC" FROM
(SELECT
    sql_id,
    TO_CHAR(TRUNC((elapsed_time/1000000)/3600),'FM9900') || ':' ||
    TO_CHAR(TRUNC(MOD((elapsed_time/1000000),3600)/60),'FM00') || ':' ||
    TO_CHAR(MOD((elapsed_time/1000000),60),'FM00') AS elapsed_time, --ESSE CAMPO É A SOMA DE TODO O TEMPO DE ESPERA, NAO DE APENAS UMA EXECUCAO
    to_char(EXECUTIONS) as EXECUTIONS
FROM    gv$sql
ORDER BY elapsed_time DESC)
WHERE ROWNUM < 10 ---top 10
/
```

**Note:** If possible, I'd like to have the average time in hour as well rather than seconds, such as in the query above.

Comment: The data type for column `ELAPSED_TIME` in the `V$SQL` view is `NUMBER`. Perhaps the [INTERVAL](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SUTIL/GUID-169DE9FB-36A5-4087-9857-7F03DCF8D3C6.htm) data type is more suitable to your requirement?

Comment: Yes, this column store the time in microseconds, is there other column is v$sql which store this value in interval datatype? I didn't find it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why are you converting the `microseconds` to `date` and then again back to the `seconds`?

I think the following query will fulfill your requirement:

> ```
> SELECT
>     SQL_ID,
>     ELAPSED_TIME_CHAR, --change here
>     TRUNC(ELAPSED_TIME, 2)   AS "TOTAL_ELAPSED_TIME_SECS", --change here
>     EXECUTIONS,
>     TRUNC(ELAPSED_TIME / EXECUTIONS, 2) "AVG_TIME_BY_EXECUTION_SEC" --change here
> FROM
>     (
>         SELECT
>             SQL_ID,
>             ELAPSED_TIME / 1000000 AS ELAPSED_TIME, --change here
>             TO_CHAR(TRUNC((ELAPSED_TIME / 1000000) / 3600), 'FM9900')
>             || ':' || TO_CHAR(TRUNC(MOD((ELAPSED_TIME / 1000000), 3600) / 60), 'FM00')
>             || ':' || TO_CHAR(MOD((ELAPSED_TIME / 1000000), 60), 'FM00') AS ELAPSED_TIME_CHAR, 
>             TO_CHAR(EXECUTIONS) AS EXECUTIONS
>         FROM GV$SQL
>         ORDER BY ELAPSED_TIME DESC
>     )
> WHERE ROWNUM < 10 ---top 10
> /
> ```

Cheers!!